# laravel обрезать текст

Tags: laravel

есть текст который я заношу через редактор summernote, при выводе текста нужно обрезать его до 200
пробовал так

```
  {!!Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($post->text,200)!!}
```

Но так не срабатывает
Так же пробовал так:

```
{{Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($post->text,200)}}
```

Но тогда выводятся стили и теги вместе с текстом

Answer (score 0):

для корректной обрезки надо удалить сначала теги вот так должно работать

```
{{Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(strip_tags($post->text),200)}}
```